# Running a java program in a loop in Unix

Tags: regex, unix, ksh

I have a unix script where I get the following arguments from command line:

```
startDate=$1
endDate=$2
```

I want to check both dates whether they are in yyyyMMdd format or not? How can I do that? If the format is incorrect, I want to exit the program.

I am running a java spring batch program in the same script as below:

```
java commandLineJobRunner jobConfig.xml myJob currDate=$currDate
```

Basically I am passing a job parameter viz. `currDate` to `myJob` spring batch job.

I want to loop above program such that the program should run for all dates between `startDate` and `endDate` that is for `currDate=startDate` to `currDate=endDate` with `currDate` incrementing by a day in each loop.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Which variant of Unix are you using? The GNU `date` command has very powerful tools for representing dates and for doing calculations on dates, but that's no help if you're on Solaris or AIX.  Which shell are you using?  That might also affect the solution.  Do you have Perl available? Can you install extra modules for it?

Comment: I am using Korn Shell. And no perl is not available. Also I can not install extra modules for it.

Comment: And why don't you take the `startDate` and `endDate` as parameters of you java program, and just do the checks and the loop in java ?

Comment: OK; Korn shell is about as powerful as Bash; that's good. If you don't have Perl available, which O/S are you working on?  Obviously, if Perl is not available, you can't install extensions for it.  You've left unanswered (except by inference) the main question — which version of Unix are you working on?

Comment: @FlorentBayle: As I said, its a spring batch program with reader processor writer.. So what you are suggesting would be more complex.

Comment: It shouldn't be very much more complex given that you already process one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BASH/ksh for basic validation of `startDate` in `yyyMMDD` you can use:

```
[[ "$startDate" == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]] && echo "valid"
```

To get next day from `$startDate` you can use:

```
nextDay=`date '+%Y%m%d' -d "$startDate next day"`
```

Comment: At the very least, you should constrain the 10s digit of the month to 0 or 1, and the 10s digit of the day to 0 to 3; you probably shouldn't allow dates in the first millennium (AD 999 and earlier), and probably not in the fourth millennium (AD 3001 or later).  So, your validation is very crude; basically, just checking that it is an 8-digit string, but allowing through 01234567 which is nonsense pretty much however you slice it as a date.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Agreed that's why I wrote it is a *basic validation*. I can easily write a more complex regex here to validate month/date/year parts using `=~` operator but I just didn't see any effort (or requirement) in OP. But your point well taken, I will edit it,

Comment: Another option is to let this be a basic validation and check `$?` of `date` for validating since any regex will struggle to validate 28/29 feb dates.